# complicated matlab image processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signals

I have a really weird question. 
Let's assume i have an oscillogram like the one shown below.
[image]
<sub>(source: [engineeringvista.com](http://audio.engineeringvista.com/AudioKits/Model-1/Test%20results/Pentode%2010kHz.gif))</sub>

I need to -somehow- capture the points that compose the signal and afterwards try to make a Fourier analysis and plot the harmonics of the signal.
Do you think such an operation could be done in matlab or any other software?

Comment: Sure it can. Are you totally sure you dont have the digital points for that screenshot, or that you cannot use a DAQ for capture the data?

Comment: Unless you are keen on using the oscillogram output, you can try to approximate this sine wave in matlab and then use fft function and then plot them. It should give you a peak at the frequency of sine wave and corresponding lower valued peaks at harmonics.

Comment: @hypfco Unfortunately i have only the printed oscillogram.

Comment: @ShantanuDeshpande well i can approximate the function but i need at least some points. Do u suggest i can read them out of the oscillogram? That would have a significant error though.

Comment: @sayidjetzenden if you have to use the printed oscillogram output then it becomes difficult. I am not sure if this would help but you could try reading the amplitude and frequency from the oscillogram plot and then use that to create your function in matlab.

Comment: @ShantanuDeshpande, i was thinking of a more automated way to read the values. In the signal shown there's not much problem in entering the values by hand, but if the signal is more abstract there's a huge error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This forum is not a Give Me the Code service!!!...

Having said that, here is precisely what you requested, with the code profusely commented and plotting the image processing steps :).....

```
%% Processing
% Reading Image
X0=imread('Pentode 10kHz.gif');
X1=512*(X0([21:219],[15:263]));
imshow(512*(1-X1));
X2=X1;
% Removing Division Dotted Lines and Axis
X2(5:5:end,:)=[];
X2(:,5:5:end)=[];
imshow(512*(1-X2));

%% Evaluating
% Obtain Maximums per Points
[~,i0]=max(X2);
% Setting the Proper Scaling
[lx,lt]=size(X2);
xmax=8*2; %2V per division, 8 divisions
tmax=10*20e-6; % 20us per division, 10 divisions
% Applying Time Scaling
t0=(1:lt)'/lt*tmax; % 200us total
% Remove Spurious Points
t0=t0(i0>1);
% Applying Volt Scaling
x0=xmax/2-i0(i0>1)'/lx*xmax;

%% Signal
plot(t0,x0)
xlabel('Time [s]');
ylabel('Volts [V]')

%% Fourier Transform
ln=length(x0);
h=fftshift(fft(x0))/1000; % f in kHz
h0=abs(h);p0=phase(h);
fmax=1/tmax*ln/2/1000; % F in kHz
f1=(0:(ln/2+1))'/ln*fmax;
h1=[h0(ln/2);2*h0(ln/2:end)];
plot(f1,h1)
axis([0 100 0 1])
xlabel('Frequency [kHz]')
ylabel('Spectral Magnitude [x/kHz]')
```

Check finally the Fourier Transform. Note the proper scales, and the single point around 10kHz, which is the correct value. Note that, because having only two periods of the signal, the FT is **not** the best method for confirming the frequency and yes, the period in this case is.

[image]
[image]

Greetings.............

Comment: Well it seems like a reasonable representation. But can u explain the lines of the code? Plus i noticed that the signal doesnt start from 0,0.

Comment: Well it is because.. the image curve do not start from zero!... The code essentially extracts all lines and dots, take the maximums per each point,  and make the proper scaling after that :)

Comment: Surely if you are confident the signal was capture on a locked loop, the hereobtained data can be patched accordingly.......

Comment: It seems that i need a step by step explanation because i have no previous experience with image processing. Would be really glad if you could add the code for Fourier analysis and the harmonics I am actually in search of.

Comment: Though I wanted to plot the harmonics the one on top of the other (on top of the original signal) not as a frequency spectrum. Whatsmore i dont get the following in the code: 

    X1=512*(X0([21:219],[15:263])); %why 512? are those probes? and why form 21:219 and 15:263 ??
% Removing Division Dotted Lines and Axis
X2(5:5:end,:)=[]; % how did you choose the numbers and the step?
X2(:,5:5:end)=[]; %same as above

Comment: Hehhehe.. that is even quite easy to do. And even more, you can obtain easily the THD figure -which is actually the final purpose. But i guess i already win my cookie today with this complete response!...

Comment: Your solution is working, theres no doubt in it. But i still dont get the code. Maybe i should read a book about signal/image processing based on matlab.

Comment: Hehheh.. The image is just a zero-one matrix and the numbers 21:219 and 12:263 are just the boundary pixels... of the plot box... By constraining the matrix to its contents let outside all the "decoratives" of the plots you provide. After that, you can realize the manufacturer placed the dotted division lines five pixels each starting from the 5th pixel, so the 5:5:end lines just remove the `x` and the `y` dotted lines. And because the axis is just another line, they went removed automatically on this process...

Comment: Check the `imshow` lines, and there you will see how the image is getting cleaner and cleaner...

Comment: And well, i dont reccomend you to read too much about image processing because you maybe will get deviated... There a lot of things there, but as you see, the problem got solved just with simple functions... Detection of edges here, is actually useless..........

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have another problem regarding the tilde operator. What does it do?

Comment: Plus my goal is to actually have something like [link](http://i.imgur.com/M3u3Eli.png)

Comment: The tilde operator `A'` is just the transposition operator `aij=aji'`

Comment: Maybe we could solve the Fourier Harmonics in another question, hence it is independent from this post...

Comment: Funny how you say we aren't a code writing service... and yet you wrote very elaborate code lol.  I'm guilty of the same thing though.

Comment: hehhhehe... i am almost dead by laughing about that joke :):)

Comment: @hypfco I tried imread another oscillogram and i got back >>whos X0        448x642x3            862848  uint8 why is there a 3d matrix?

Comment: Do the oscillogram looks like the first one?. It is by three when it is a coloured image: RGB, one matrix per color channel. Could you upload it as edit, to see it...